# How to include external file in Go?

Tags: go, package

I'm using LiteIDE for Go.  I have a Go file located here:

```
/Users/username/go/src/src/Helper/Helper.go
```

When I include the file using:

> import "../Helper"

I get this error:

> can't load package: /Users/username/go/src/src/projectA/main.go:4:8:
>   local import "../Helper" in non-local package

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: see https://golang.org/doc/code.html

Comment: What command did you use to build? From what I gather, to build with a 'local import' you have to indicate that your main package is also local by explicitly providing it to the build command like `go build main.go`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You import packages by import path. For package `Helper`, located in `$GOPATH/src/Helper/`, use:

```
import "Helper"
```

While they can work in some cases, relative paths aren't supported by the go toolchain, and are discouraged.

Comment: To access a struct in Helper, do I need to declare an alias on the import?  Otherwise, I get an error when trying to access a struct in Helper.

Comment: @4thSpace: You access identifiers in `Helper` just like you would any other package; `packagename.Identifer`. e.g. `fmt.Println` from the `fmt` package.